# Symbolic solutions to systems of Boolean constraints?

Tags: symbolic, boolean-computation, logic, theorem-proving

Is it possible to solve a system of Boolean constraints symbolically? I'm trying to solve systems like the following, where $X$ is the unknown Boolean expression I'm trying to find, $a, b, c$ are the Boolean variables in all the expressions including $X$ and the $p_i$, and the $p_i$ are different Boolean expressions. The arrow notation here ($\rightarrow$) refers to normal Boolean implication, not the
Mathematica [Rule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) symbol.

Each value of each variable "picks out" a different expression:

$$ X \land       a \rightarrow p_1$$
$$ X \land \lnot a \rightarrow p_2$$
$$ X \land       b \rightarrow p_3$$
$$ X \land \lnot b \rightarrow p_4$$
$$ X \land       c \rightarrow p_5$$
$$ X \land \lnot c \rightarrow p_6$$

The $p_i$ are all different from each other:

$$ i \neq j \Rightarrow \lnot(p_i \leftrightarrow p_j)$$

The $p_i$ and $X$ are all simultaneously satisfiable:

$$ X \land p_1 \land p_2 \land p_3 \land p_4 \land p_5 \land p_6 $$

The following is an example solution:

$$ X = (a \land b) \lor (a \land c) \lor (b \land c)$$

Can Mathematica find this somehow?

Comment: If you read https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Booleans.html then that seems to hint that you might be able to use something like `FindInstance[...someexpr...,{a,b,c},Booleans]` where it is going to find your `a,b,c` that are booleans IF you can find a way to write `...someexpr...` that captures your problem.  If that isn't enough for you to solve this then can you show an example `...someexpr...` or describe exactly what it is in your actual problem and what the answer should be and maybe someone can see how to do that. Does this point you in the right direction?